# discord.py how to add an image to embed.add_field

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How can I add a local image in the value of `embed.add_field(name=f'Last Match ({status})', value=`

```
    file = discord.File(f"{icon_full_path}", filename=f"{icon_png}")
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f'**{name}**', description=f'Summoner Level: {level}')
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f'attachment://{icon_png}')
    embed.add_field(name='Ranked (Solo/Duo)', value=f'{full_rank}')
    embed.add_field(name=f'Last Match ({status})', value=f'{kills} / {deaths} / {assists} \n {minions}<:minion:823209384908816404> \t {gold}<:gold:823209384942370836>')
    await ctx.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```

Comment: From the documentation I don't believe there is a way to add an image to a *field*: see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.add_field you can add a thumbnail, author image or image content, but a field seems to only accept text. If you have a screenshot where it is possible, maybe post it so others can decipher a way to realize this. Custom smilies might be possible?

Comment: The official discord.com docs also don't mention field images: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object-embed-field-structure

Comment: So there's no way to add an image? even if it's external?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot add image in the value field of `add_field`. Please refer to [discord.Embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed) for all the functions of discord.Embed class.

We use `set_image` to set image ( big in size ) and `set_thumbnail` to set an image to the top right of the embed ( like a logo ).

Depending on your usage you can use anyone of them.

If you want to embed local images you can refer to [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image) page on discord py api.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Use add_image add images

```
embed = discord.Embed(title = 'hi', description = 'cheese',color = discord.Colour.blue())
embed.add_image(url = 'insert random url here')
await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```